# Constraint satisfaction problems in Natural language processing

Tags: artificial-intelligence, natural-language-processing, constraint-satisfaction, research

I have just started learning about CSP and NLP, for which I have to write a review paper of some research articles.

The problem is that when a searched for research articles on some trusted digital libraries with the keywords CSP and NLP, there weren't many results that were related to both.

Do you have any idea on where should I start? Or if you could tell me any specific use case of CSP in NLP on which I can focus.

Thank you in advance for your responses.

Comment: I have the same problem with finding information on certain topics, but https://scholar.google.com/ has helped me a little.

Comment: @Yllka There are lots of results if you google ["natural language processing" "constraint satisfaction"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22natural+language+processing%22+%22constraint+satisfaction%22) or use Google Scholar [here](https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?q=%22natural+language+processing%22+%22constraint+satisfaction%22).